# Who did call Activity onAttachedToWindow method and when

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to know who call activity onAttachedToWindow method and when. After read these code including PhoneWindow,ViewRootImpl and ActivityThread ,I did not find the answer.
The method named onWindowFocusChanged is the same as the onAttachedToWindow method.
Who can advise.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- Please read this guide. Include your code in the post, and explain what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Finally , I find the answer . It is called by ViewRootImpl when the setView method is invoked through mDisplayListener .